Representation of pairwise aov adjusted p-value comparison



Group
Compared to Group..
adj p_value




1
2
1e-06


1
3
1e-04


1
4
1e-02


2
3
1e-01


2
4
0.08



I run a pairwise adjusted p-value comparison from a AOV for data gathered from around 1000 groups, getting results in the way that are represented in the scheme above. Given the number of p-values and the difficulty to visualize each group pair comparison, I wonder if it´s possible, and how, to build a graphic pairwise matrix representation that include all pairwise p-values.
As a result, I expect the following type of graphic representaion..
representation of expected results

This is a simple table?

The image seems to be just text.  If you want a graphical representation try plot(TukeyHSD(aov(yield ~ block, npk))) .

m <- matrix(NA, 4, 4)
m[upper.tri(m)] <- df$`adj p_value`


     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]   NA 1e-06 1e-04 1e-01
[2,]   NA    NA 1e-02 8e-02
[3,]   NA    NA    NA 1e-06
[4,]   NA    NA    NA    NA


Note that you didn't supply the p-value for 3 compared to 4, so the p-value vector is recycled with a warning.
